# Running Toxiproxy in docker containers with MacOS

Tags: docker, proxy

Very basic question about proxying inside docker containers in OSX: I am running a toxiproxy docker container with:

```
docker run --name proxy -p 8474:8474 -p 19200:19200 shopify/toxiproxy
```

and an Elasticsearch container:

```
docker run --name es -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch:6.8.6
```

I want toxiproxy to redirect the traffic from the `Elasticsearch:9200 container to localhost:19200. I config the toxiproxy with:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:8474/proxies -d "{ \"name\": \"proxy_es\", \"listen\": \"0.0.0.0:19200\", \"upstream\": \"localhost:9200\", \"enabled\": true}"
```

Now, I would expect that:

```
curl -XGET localhost:19200/_cat
```

would point me to the Elasticsearch endpoint. But get:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any idea why this is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From inside the toxiproxy container, localhost:9200 does not resolve to es container.

This is because by default these containers are attached to default network. On the default network, localhost refers to the localhost of the container. It does not resolve to the localhost of the host machine (where docker-machine is running).

You can use the host network by adding --net=host for this to work. A better approach would be to create a new network, and run all containers in that network.

`docker run --name proxy -p 8474:8474 -p 19200:19200 --net host shopify/toxiproxy`

`docker run --name es -p 9200:9200 --net host elasticsearch:6.8.6`

You localhost should be resolvable in both ways

Comment: I tried the using a docker bridge network and the proxy does not behave as expected. Maybe the `listen` and `upstream` are somehow wrongly set?